# python - pyautogui doesn't returns RBG value (even though I add the code: sys.platform = '_')

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am using the IDLE to import pyautogui to use the function `pyautogui.displayMousePosition()`on Mac but the RGB result is `RGB: (NaN, NaN, NaN)` and I am search for the solution that someone suggested to the below code at the IDLE or terminal:

```
import sys 
sys.platform = '_'
```

But it result other error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 1747, in displayMousePosition
    pixelColor = pyscreeze.screenshot().getpixel(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 477, in _screenshot_osx
    im = Image.open(tmpFilename)
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
```

Dennis

Comment: post your full code so that we can diagnose the problem

Comment: HI Zain, Thank you for your asking!

I just realize that it needs to install `pip3 install Pillow` on Mac to activate the `Image`

And I entire code as follow (After I install Pillow and allow terminal and IDLE to access my screen)
```
import pyautogui
import sys 
sys.platform = '_'
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```
But there is a problem which is the refreshing result (X & Y position and RGB) of  `pyautogui.displayMousePosition()` is much slow that is delay with my mouse moving

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2 monitors, it shows the color on the primary monitor and it says NaN on the second monitor.